# How to fill an angle interval in a wind rose plot using PyPlot lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have angle interval such **init angle=10º** and **end angle=20º**, and would like to fill the area with some colour using a polar plot (wind rose) with **PyPlot lib**

[Wind rose plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgp5I.png)

Is that possible using this kind of subplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in the code below 
not sure if is there any easiest way to do, but that definitely works...

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

angles   = [45,60,100,120,270,300]
angles_t = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
r = [0, 1]

for i in range(0,len(angles),2):
    init = angles[i]
    end  = angles[i+1]
    for j in range(init, end):
        ang = (j*(2*pi))/360
        theta=[ang,ang]
        ax.plot(theta,r,'r-')

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(pi/2.0)    

plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.show()
```